# How to change x interval labels in GNUPlot for python?

Tags: python, graph, gnuplot

Right now my graphing function looks this.

```
def makeGraph(data, name, title, xlab):
    g = Gnuplot.Gnuplot(persist=1)
    g.title(title)
    g('set terminal png truecolor')
    g('set output "'+name+'"')
    g('set ylabel "# of Reservations"')
    g('set xlabel "'+xlab+'"')
    g('set style data histograms')
    g('set style fill solid 1.0 border -1')
    g.plot(data)
```

As you can see in the photo, everything is working as expected. Now, I would like to change the markings on the x axis (0-6) to Sun-Sat. I have been searching around, but have yet to successfully get it to work.

[image: How graph outputs]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node295.html). One way to achieve what you need is to use a command such as:

```
set xtics ("Sun" 0, "Mon" 1, "Tue" 2, "Wed" 3, "Thu" 4, "Fri" 5, "Sat" 6)
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you! My issue was I didn't have the numbers following the labels so it wasn't working.